# Ngrams with a dataset java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

hi i am trying to use ngrams on this data set ( number of attacks) but i am confused to how to merge the 2 methods together so that the n-grams can spot the frequency on how many times they appear. i am just trying to data process but i am confused. any help would be appreciated thank you.
This is what i have done so far. as you can see the main method holds the dataset but how can i merge all methods together so that the Ngrams runs on the data. thank you

```
    public class MainProcess {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
       FileReader readhandle = new 
       FileReader("/Users/muhammad/Desktop/ADFA- 
       LD/Attack_Data_Master/Adduser_1/UAD-Adduser-1-=1.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(readhandle);
       String line = null;
       while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
       {
          System.out.println(line);
       }
       br.close();
       readhandle.close();
    }

    public class Ngrams {


        ArrayList<String> nGrams = new ArrayList<String>();

        public void generateNGrams(String str, int n) {

          if (str.length() == n ) {
              int counter = 0;
              while (counter < n) {
                nGrams.add(str.substring(counter));
                counter++;
              }
              return;
          }

          int counter = 0;
          String gram = "";
          while (counter < n) {
              gram += str.charAt(counter);
              counter++;
          }
          nGrams.add(gram);
          generateNGrams(str.substring(1), n);
        }

        public void printNGrams() {



          for (String str : nGrams) {
              System.out.println(str);
          }
        }}








}
```

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the question? It's a bit confusing. Show us some sample input and what your expected behaviour is and how the actual behaviour differs from your expectations. And I'm not sure what the code you posted is supposed to do. It looks like you have a main method that prints a file to `stdout`, and then another class that never gets used.

Comment: hi sorry for the confusion, what im trying to do is read what is in my .txt file (has rows of numbers, no comma just numbers with spaces, it is a dataset). and put the data from the .txt file into an array so that i can use that array to do an N-gram feature selection.